# How to make config file for set the javascript file path

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need one help.I need to set one config file for set Javascript file path and include that file in html page.Suppose i need to include the below file path into my HTML page.

```
 <script src="/gopasto/controller/homeProfileController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

from the above link i need to set  dynamically `/gopasto/` only means i will set this path from config file.When i want to change this i can change inside only in config file.Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Need to know more about the config file. What language is it written in and/or what interprets it?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 : i need to only set the `/gopasto/` in config file and it will fetch to each javascript link.because at any time i can change inside the config file according to my requirement. it may me in javascript or jquery.

Comment: If you want to build the `src` client-side then you will need to "lazyload" your script, and any other scripts that depend on it. [This article](https://friendlybit.com/js/lazy-loading-asyncronous-javascript/) gives a pretty good idea of the issues surrounding lazyloading.

Answer (score 0):

There's several different ways you can link dynamically using Laravel.

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('css/something.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Another example:

```
<link href="/css/something.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Generate a URL for an asset using the current scheme of the request (HTTP or HTTPS):

`$url = asset('folder/file.js');`

using Laravel's Blade:

```
{{ link_to('/assets/file/file.js', 'Link') }}
```

Maybe this section in the documentation will be helpful for you:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#urls

Comment: @ Kaizen : i am not clear from your answer.Can you clarify by using example in the post ?